# Using integers in GLSL fragment shaders - experiencing unexplained artifacts

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, texture-mapping

I have a hexagonal grid that I want to texture.  I want to use a single texture with 16 distinct subtextures arranged in a 4x4 grid.    Each "node" in the grid has an image type, and I want to smoothly blend between them.  My approach for implementing this is to render triangles in pairs, and encode the 4 image types on all vertices in the two faces, as well as a set of 4 weighting factors (which are the barycentric coordinates for the two tris).  I can then use those two things to blend smoothly between any combination of image types.

[image: 4x4 Texture]

Here is the fragment shader I'm using.  The problems are arising from the use of `int` types, but I don't understand why.  If i only use the first four sub-textures then i can change `idx` to be `float` and hardcode the Y-coord to be 0, and then it then works as i expect.

```glsl
vec2 offset(int idx) {
    vec2 v = vec2(idx % 4, idx / 4);
    return v / 4.0;
}

void main(void) {   
    //
    // divide the incoming UVs into one of 16 regions.  The 
    // offset() function should take an integer from 0..15 
    // and return the offset to that region in the 4x4 map
    //
    vec2 uv = v_uv / 4.0;

    //
    // The four texture regions involved at 
    // this vertex are encoded in vec4 t_txt.  The same
    // values are stored at all vertices, so this doesn't 
    // vary across the triangle
    //
    int ia = int(v_txt.x);
    int ib = int(v_txt.y);
    int ic = int(v_txt.z);
    int id = int(v_txt.w);
    
    //
    // Use those indices in the offset function to get the
    // texture sample at that point
    //      
    vec4 ca = texture2D(txt, uv + offset(ia)); 
    vec4 cb = texture2D(txt, uv + offset(ib)); 
    vec4 cc = texture2D(txt, uv + offset(ic)); 
    vec4 cd = texture2D(txt, uv + offset(id)); 
    
    //
    // Merge them with the four factors stored in vec4 v_tfact.
    // These vary for each vertex
    //
    fragcolour = ca * v_tfact.x 
               + cb * v_tfact.y 
               + cc * v_tfact.z 
               + cd * v_tfact.w;
    
}
```

Here is what's happening:

[image: artifacts]

(My "pair of triangles" are actually about 20 and you can see their structure in the artifacts, but the effect is the same)

This artifacting behaves a bit like z-fighting: moving the scene around makes it all shimmer and shift wildly.

Why doesn't this work as I expect?

One solution I can fall back on is to simply use a 1-dimensional texture map, with all 16 sub-images in a horizontal line, then i can switch everything to floating point since I won't need the modulo/integer-divide process to map `idx->x,y`, but this feels clumsy and I'd at least like to understand what's going on here.

Here is what it should look like, albeit with only 4 of the sub-images in use:

[image: expected]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 5.4.1. Conversion and Scalar Constructors](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#constructors)

> When constructors are used to convert a floating-point type to an integer type, the fractional part of the floating-point value is dropped.

Hence `int(v_txt.x)` does not round `v_txt.x`, it truncates `v_txt.x`

You have to [`round`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/round.xhtml) the values to the nearest integer before constructing an integral value:

```c
int ia = int(round(v_txt.x));
int ib = int(round(v_txt.y));
int ic = int(round(v_txt.z));
int id = int(round(v_txt.w));
```

Alternatively add 0.5 before constructing the integral value:

```c
int ia = int(v_txt.x + 0.5);
int ib = int(v_txt.y + 0.5);
int ic = int(v_txt.z + 0.5);
int id = int(v_txt.w + 0.5);
```

Comment: ah i see, even though my `v_txt` IDs are integers (1.0, 2.0, 3.0 etc) because i represent them as floats they're being interpolated across the tri as `0.999, 1.001, 0.999, 1.001` etc, so simply discarding is not enough.  Seems obvious now you've pointed it out!  Thanks :-)